# Dictionary in Python not printing updated key/value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary in my Selenium script in which one of the keys ("data") is updated afterwards because it's not a fixed value, so I get it with Selenium:

```
fields_personal = {
    "data": "", 
    "nome": "João da Silva",
    "documento": "CPF",
    "numero": "123.456.789-10",
    "telefone": "(01)23456-7890",
    "email": "teste@email.com"
}

for data, value in fields_personal.items():
    element = driver.find_element_by_id(data)
    element.send_keys(value)
    if data == "data":
        for item in element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
            option = item.text.strip()
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='data']/option[1]").click()
            fields_personal["data"] = option
            break
    print("{}: {}".format(data, value))
```

No problem with that, it works fine. But when I try to print the dictionary with `print("{}: {}".format(data, value))`, or simply `print(data, value)` it prints "data" key with empty value, as if it hasn't been updated:

```
data:  
nome: João da Silva
documento: CPF
numero: 123.456.789-10
telefone: (01)23456-7890
email: teste@email.com
```

The only way I can print the updated dictionary is calling `pprint.pprint(fields_personal)`, since I want it structured line by line, but this outputs the result formatted with quotes and curly braces, which I don't want:

```
{'data': '28/06/2021',
 'documento': 'CPF',
 'email': 'teste@email.com',
 'nome': 'João da Silva',
 'numero': '123.456.789-10',
 'telefone': '(01)23456-7890'}
```

So, how can I print it line by line, without quotes and curly braces *and* updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if` block, you updates `fields_personal["data"]`; however, when you print it as `data`, this is the original value read at the start of `for` loop.

You can move your print inside the block, adding an `else` to the `if` to not print two times the same value.

```py
for data, value in fields_personal.items():
    element = driver.find_element_by_id(data)
    element.send_keys(value)
    if data == "data":
        for item in element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
            option = item.text.strip()
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='data']/option[1]").click()
            fields_personal["data"] = option
            break
        print("{}: {}".format("data", fields_personal["data"])
    else:
        print("{}: {}".format(data, value))
```

However, if you can just wait after the `for` block, it would be better.

```py
for data, value in fields_personal.items():
    element = driver.find_element_by_id(data)
    element.send_keys(value)
    if data == "data":
        for item in element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option"):
            option = item.text.strip()
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='data']/option[1]").click()
            fields_personal["data"] = option
            break

for key, value in fields_personal.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```